# Location to keep Ansible custom modules

Tags: ansible

In the following directory structure I have to create a zip of "anisble" directory. The idea is to put everything inside the ansible directory like playbook, roles, inventory details and custom modules into a zip package and
its contents should not have any dependency on anything outside "ansible" directory.

```
<home>
   |<user>
       |__ansible
        |_____playbook.yml
            |_____inventory/
            |           |____myHosts
            |
            |_____library/
            |       |___my_Custom_module.py
            |_roles
            |   |____role1
            |____role2
```

I cannot use: "`/home/$USER/.ansible/plugins/modules/`" as this will make solution user specific and "`/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules/`" is outside of the ansible directory and does need privileges(which user does not have)

**Question:**

1. Is there any possible place were my_custom_module.py can be placed so it will automatically get picked by ansible while running? This must be somewhere inside "ansible" directory.
2. If I do this before running the ansible playbook, it works but is there anyway to programmatically do it from ansible playbook before using the custom module ?

   export  ANSIBLE_LIBRARY=library/my_custom_module.py
3. Is there anyway I can provide the path of the custom module relative to "ansible" directory ? either in any conf file or env variable ? Note that I cannot use `/etc ,/usr/ etc` . Everything had to be inside ansible directory,
4. Is it even possible ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a file `ansible.cfg` inside of your `ansible` directory and then set the `DEFAULT_MODULE_PATH` variable (`library`) in that file:

```
[defaults]
library = ./library
```

More info can be found in the [Ansible documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#ansible-configuration-settings) for the Ansible configuration.

Here's what the documentation says about this setting:

> Description:  Colon separated paths in which Ansible will search for Modules.
>
> Type: pathspec
>
> Default:  ~/.ansible/plugins/modules:/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules
>
> Ini Section:  defaults
>
> Ini Key:  library
>
> Environment:  ANSIBLE_LIBRARY

Comment: thank you for your response, what if I need to use the custom_module in any of my role ? I tested with your suggestion, playbook are picking up the module but when I move the code to roles and try to use the custom module its not able to recognize it. Can you please guide me on this.

Comment: I am guessing that `./library` is a valid path for playbook but not for `tasks/main.yml` in roles

Comment: Can you try `${PWD}/library` as a value? That should point to the directory from where you run Ansible, i.e. where the playbook is located...

Comment: Not worked, Do I need to refresh anything or just the changes are ok ?